# CommandAcceptanceException when adding a foreign key to a table in mySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm new to Spring, Hibernate and Java Development. I get this error when I start my application:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table tv_series add constraint FKrmhxb8lbsb5jm2no1aftgbg7f foreign key (fk_tv_series_author) references tv_series_author (id)" via JDBC Statement
```

I've been looking for a solution for three hours, but everything I tried didn't work.
I know that there are similar questions on this site, but none of the answers worked for me.

This is the Entity code for the mother table

```
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_tv_series_author")   
    private TvSeriesAuthor author;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_cast")   
    private List<Actor> cast;
    
    @Column
    private String title;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_streaming_provider") 
    private List<StreamingProvider> streamingProviderlist;
```

This is the Entity code for the child table

```
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column
    private String name;
    
    @Column
    private String group;
```

These are my application properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myMediaApp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

This is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>it.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myMediaApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myMediaApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

In your properties file,  please add the hibernate dialect

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

For connecting any hibernate application with the database, it is required to provide the configuration of SQL dialect. Maybe the default configuration is not correct, so try with this or think in similar lines.